# Slow disk drive performance or letter conflict

Tags: windows-7, drive-letter

I've made a fresh install of Windows 10 on my dads PC. Disconnected existing HDD and SSD and installed it on a brand new SSD. Upon reconnecting the HDD, Windows boot time went up to around 5 to 10 minutes.

First time after boot, the drive letters for that HDD weren't assigned. Now they automatically assigned, but just to make sure, the I am changing to something manual. The process is taking extremely long time. Even opening Disk Manager was taking forever (left it overnight).

While there is some processing going on now (disk activity light is blinking (does that a lot during 10 minute boot), disk utilisation is 100% in Task Manager) disk read speed is extremely low. I hope this will resolve after reassigning drive letters, but what could be the issue here?

Perhaps there are a lot of permissions that are being processed? Help, holidays are ending soon :)

SSD was where most recent Windows 7 installation was, while HDD was where an older Windows 7 installation was.

Comment: Seems one of the additional drives you added is bad. Try disconnecting all HDDs other than the brand new SSD. Then one by one add an HDD and boot the PC. The one that causes the boot to be sluggish is the problematic HDD

Comment: Yeah seems like the HDD is bad. I could hear it stop few times. Any ideas how to boot to windows without it indexing (or whatever it does) it? Takes forever.

Comment: I dont think indexing is the issue. Windows slows down when it tries to access it. Buying a new one is the only option AFAIK.

Comment: Ended up booting using Hirens Boot CD, and using `dd` to clone the partitions ignoring all errors. Then mounted the raw image using `OSFMount`. Windows wasn't recognising it, but chkdsk repaired it so I was able to recover everything.